# why the function strcat not working?

Tags: c, strcpy, strcat

I have some code in C, I want to connect the ssid with the string "option" in the for loop

```
  void ApListCallback(ScanResult *pApList)
    {
        int i;

      printf("Find %d APs: \r\n", pApList->ApNum);

        for (i=0;i<pApList->ApNum;i++){
            char *ssid=pApList->ApList[i].ssid;
            char *temp=strcat(strcat("<option>",ssid),"</option>");
            printf("=======%s=======\r\n",ssid);
            printf("-------%s-------\r\n",temp);
            strcpy(ApListCallbackSelectStr, temp);
        }

        printf("---%s--\r\n",ApListCallbackSelectStr);
        }
```

and I get the result:

> Find 11 APs:
>
> ```
> =======MODIM FASHION=======
> -------<option>-------
> ==============
> -------<option>-------
> =======360WiFi-6888=======
> -------<option>-------
> =======HAME_A5_037d=======
> -------<option>-------
> =======sweet baby=======
> -------<option>-------
> =======ringierguest=======
> -------<option>-------
> =======JIMMY 3G=======
> -------<option>-------
> =======MF70_9BC5E1=======
> -------<option>-------
> =======Bert-Co=======
> -------<option>-------
> ---<option>--
> ```

why the function strcat not working?

Comment: What's your expected output

Comment: You shouldn't printf `\r\n` either (unless you are deliberately generating a windows textfile while running under Unix environment). In Windows, printing `\n` will cause the file to contain `\r\n`.

Comment: Each iteration of your loop calls `strcpy(ApListCallbackSelectStr` which overwrites what was in that buffer; so the effect of this code (if fixed) is to print out each item and then print the last line twice; is that really what you intended?

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes. you are right. I need to use `strcat` instead of `strcpy` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"<option>"` is readonly in the C language, so trying to write data to it, should actually cause a segmentation fault, you need a pointer to allocated memory to write into it, the following should work

```
void ApListCallback(ScanResult *pApList)
{
    int i;

    printf("Find %d APs: \r\n", pApList->ApNum);

    for (i=0;i<pApList->ApNum;i++)
    {
        char *ssid=pApList->ApList[i].ssid;
        /* reserve memory for the characters and point to it with temp */
        char *temp=malloc(strlen(ssid) + 18);
        if (temp != NULL)
        {
            /* copy the first part of the resulting string into temp */
            strcpy(temp, "<option>");
            /* append ssid to temp */
            strcat(temp, ssid);
            /* append the literal "</option>" to temp */
            strcat(temp, "</option>");
            strcpy(ApListCallbackSelectStr, temp);
            /* release the reserved memory */
            free(temp);
        }
    }

    printf("---%s--\r\n",ApListCallbackSelectStr);
}
```

the `strlen` function will return the number of characters in the string `ssid`, and the number of characters of `<option></option>` is `17`, you also need an extra `'\0'` character that marks the end of the string, so total `strlen(ssid) + 18`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It seems I use Java thinking in C language XD

Answer (score 3):

```
char *temp=strcat(strcat("<option>",ssid),"</option>");
```

Here you are trying to concatenate to a string literal `"<option>"`. The problem is: modifying string literals is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a string literal as the first argument to `strcat()`. The first argument needs to contain enough space to contain the original string plus the concatenated string (plus a terminating zero).

You can read about `strcat()` [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat).

Answer (score 1):

if you look up the manpage for strcat, you'll see that the first argument should be a `char[]` buffer to hold the results.  Unlike newer languages, strings in C are arrays of chars, and must be manipulated as such.  Also, strcat only copies one argument, not a varags list.  Try

```
char line[1000] = "";
strcat(line, "<option>");
strcat(line, ssid);
strcat(line, "</option>");
printf("%s\n", line);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers show how to fix and still use strcat. However the much better way to write this code in C is:

```
printf("=======%s=======\n",ssid);
printf("-------<option>%s</option>-------\n", ssid);
```

You don't need to allocate memory or anything.

If you are also compiling every line into a string then you must also take care of the buffer size you are writing into. You have to protect against buffer overflow on `ApListCallbackSelectStr`. Here is one way to do it:

```
char *begin = ApListCallbackSelectStr;
char *const end = begin + sizeof ApListCallbackSelectStr;
// assuming `ApListCallbackSelectStr` is an array, not a pointer

for (i=0;i<pApList->ApNum;i++)
{    
    char const *ssid = pApList->ApList[i].ssid;
    int this = snprintf(begin, end - begin, 
                    "-------<option>%s</option>-------\n", ssid);

    if ( this < 0 || this >= end - begin )    // ran out of buffer, or other internal failure
        return; 

    printf("======%s======\n", ssid);
    printf("%*s\n", this, begin);

    begin += this;
}
```